# Java Jackson XML Parsing

Tags: java, jackson, xml-parsing

I have XML:

```
<list>
    <testcase classname="ClassName1" name="TestCaseName1" time="0.020">
        <failure message="Failure Message" type="Type of failure">Extended failure message</failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="ClassName2" name="TestCaseName2" time="0.030">
        <error message="Error Message" type="Type of failure">Extended error message</error>
    </testcase>
</list>
```

I wanna get simple class ():

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TestCase {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String classname;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "failure")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private String failureExtendedMessage;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "error")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private String errorExtendedMessage;
}
```

I don't understand, how i can get @"Failure Message"@ or @"Error Message"@
PS Sorry for my English

Comment: The names of the annotations should give you a hint about why things dont work...

Comment: The annotations are for json, you want them for xml

Comment: Which annotations i must use? Help plz!

Comment: Redid the class. The question remained.